# MS Access .mdb & .ldb database corrupted

Tags: ms-access, restore

I am using a A.mdb database. You know when connecting the database Microsoft automatically create a .ldb file. Unfortunately my pc shutdown when connecting the database. As a result after restart the PC I couldn't open the A.mdb file. The message shown A.mdb database is corrupted.

A.mdb database was password lock but after corrupted if I give the valid password the database not open and showing the password not valid.

Now I couldn't open the database. Now it shown A.mdb file with A.ldb file. Please advise me if PC shutdown with the connected .mdb database then why the database not recover after restart? Also i tried with the option Database Repair and Recovery.

Comment: and you have no backup?  I'd say the chance of opening that .mdb is slim.

Comment: Shut down cleanly or crashed/powered off?

Answer (score 1):

## Open in Safe Mode

Open the Access application with the following option:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\msaccess.exe" /safe "C:\path to mdb file\your.mdb"
```

## Open and compact/repair

Open the Access database with the `/compact` parameter:

```
C:\> "c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\msaccess.exe" /compact "C:\path to mdb file\your.mdb"
```

*Reference:* [Command-line switches for Access](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Command-line-switches-for-Access-558cfe1d-3c98-4292-bee8-1f5df9702bf1?omkt=en-GB&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

## Open the database and repair

> In Microsoft Access 2000 and later, compact and repair functionality is combined under /compact. The /repair switch is supported for backward compatibility

Open the Access database and repair it with the following parameter:

```
C:\> "c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\msaccess.exe" /repair "C:\path to mdb file\your.mdb"
```

## Bypass Startup Options

Alternatively try opening the Access database while bypassing any startup options:

- Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key
- Open Microsoft Access database with a double-click on the MDB file
- If messages pop up, keep <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> depressed and confirm any messages
- Wait for Access Database to open

*Reference:* [Bypass startup options when you open a database](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-f19b5792-5a85-4516-89b2-43a10f60f1c1)

## Last possibility

Buy a repair software

Comment: Make a copy of the file before doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Please try by deleting the .ldb file. This will clear the lock on the mdb file and should allow you to get in and try and recover your data.